# Dynamic Programming Algorithm Notation

Tags: algorithm

From Chapter 6 of Algorithms, S. Dasgupta, C. Papadimitriou, U. Vazirani, 2006.

I am trying to understand some of the psuedocode with the algorithms at the beginning of this chapter. The first one is [the topological sort linearization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH9gm.jpg) I understand the dist and min routines. But I do not understand notation `min *subscript* (u, v)∈Edges {dist(u) + l(u, v)}`. Does anyone know how to describe each piece of that particular notation. Is this cycling through ever node `u` connected to `v` by a directed edge?

My second question is the notation in the [Longest Increasing Subsequence algorithm.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqNKe.jpg) How do you interpret the `max{L(i):(i, j)∈Edges}`. What does the colon mean in this statement? And in the text I see `L(.)` and what does that mean?

Comment: I want to say that the colon means *such that*

Answer (score 0):

Both minimum and maximum need a domain to operate on. I.e. from a specific set, those operators return the maximum or minimum element.

Both notations are variants to define this domain. The first one basically says: "Considering all pairs `(u, v)` in the `Edges` set, find the minimum value of `dist(u) + l(u, v)`.

The second variant defines the set of values: `{L(i) : (i, j) ∈ Edges}` is the set of all values `L(i)` that can be formed from the pairs `(i, j)` in the `Edges` set. Then, the maximum operator finds the maximum value from this set.

So the differences are marginal. The first one specifies a domain and an expression that maps every element of the domain to a value. The second one directly specifies the set to pick the maximum element from.

Actually, both variants can be used interchangeably. It is probably just some inconsistency between the authors that the book used both.

Comment: Thank you for your help.. But on the second one - how did you know to say it that way? I am not  as familiar with these types of statements.

Comment: It's just how it is. The first part in the braces is the expression and the second part (after the colon) some constraint. Maybe another example: `{j : (i, j) ∈ Edges}` is the set of neighbors of vertex `i` in a graph. It reads: "all `j` such that the pair `(i, j)` is the the `Edges` set, i.e. `i` and `j` are connected".